# Псевдорандомный идентификатор, базированный на числе

Tags: javascript

Скажем, есть числа — id пользователей. Требуется для каждого id сгенерировать (псевдо)случайное число в установленном диапазоне (напр, 1 - 32). При том, что должен быть разброс в зависимости от id пользователей, даже если они отличаются на единицу. При одном и том же id, должно всегда возвращаться одно и то же число. При этом хотелось бы добиться адекватной энтропии.

Наглядно:

```
function getNumber(id, range = 32) {
    // ...

    return result
}

getNumber(123) // Например, 31
getnumber(124) // Например, 5
getNumber(123) // Снова, например, 31
```

Какие есть наиболее быстрые алгоритмы для решения такой проблемы?

Comment: всего 32 пользователя? :)

Comment: `Random` потянет?

Comment: @Grundy неее, для разных id юзеров может сгенериться одинаковые числа, главное что бы они были в установленном диапазоне

Comment: Взять любую хеш-функцию и остаток от деления на 32.

Comment: @AGS17 Random не создаст ситуацию, что при одном и том же id будет генерироваться одно и то же число

Comment: @AlexeyTen погуглил хэш-функции, действительно, вариант, спасибо

Comment: Ну или взять простейший ГПСЧ

Comment: @AlexeyTen слишком громоздко. Простая хэш-функция спасает ситуацию